# belongsToMany with parent-child relationship in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models that are related to each other with a `belongsToMany` relationship. The models are `Game` and `Category`. Of course, the tables for both are `games` and `categories`. The `Category` model, has its own parent-child relationship.

Basically this is my "simplified" structure:

```
Table game:
id          unsigned integer
name        string

Table categories:
id          unsigned integer
name        string
parent_id   unsigned integer nullable
```

The `parent_id` column is `null` when the category has no parent, but it has an existing id referencing a row in the same table if it is a children of some other category.

```
Table category_game
category_id unsigned integer
game_id     unsigned integer
```

The `category_id` column, references `id` on `categories` table. It should reference only the top category that a game belongs to. A game can belong to many different categories, but in the pivot table, there should only be a reference to the parents categories. For example if I had this structure of categories:

```
Category 1
  Category 2
    Category 4
  Category 3
    Category 9
Category 5
  Category 6
  Category 7
    Category 8
```

I would like to have the following information for my games 1 and 2:

```
category_id  game_id
          3        1
          5        1
          1        2
```

And that should mean that my game 1 has categories: 3, 9, 5, 6, 7 and 8.
While my game 2 has categories: 1, 2, 4, 3 and 9

I understand that my Laravel models should have this:

```
class Game {
    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany( Category::class );
    }
}

class Category{
    public function games(){
        return $this->belongsToMany( Game::class );
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to retrieve the children categories using Eloquent. I know the `belongsToMany` method has more parameters that might help with my problem, but I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Is there a limit to how deep the categories can be nested?

Comment: I would say no, but if it is a requirement, then I will be Ok with organizing my categories with a max depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your models:

```php
class Category {
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}

class Game {
    public function getAllCategoriesAttribute() {
        $result = collect();
        $children = function($categories) use(&$result, &$children) {
            if($categories->isEmpty()) return;
            $result = $result->merge($categories);
            $children($categories->pluck('children')->collapse());
        };
        $children($this->categories);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the categories like this:

```
Game::find($id)->allCategories;
```

Comment: I used your code and I got this error message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`category_id` = 1 and `categories`.`category_id` is not null)

Comment: Was your comment meant for the other answer?

Comment: No sir, it was for your answer. When I used your code, I got the error message that I posted.

Comment: Turns out you were right. I was missing the foreign key `parent_id` in the Parent-Child relationship, so it was looking for a column called `category_id`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Model categoryGame for table `category_game`

```
class CategoryGame{
 public function childCategories() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id','category_id');
 }
}
```

You can access

```
$games = App\CategoryGame::all();

foreach ($games as $game ) {
    foreach ($game->childCategories as $category) {
      echo $category->name;
     }
}
```

Let me know if not works

Comment: I tested your approach and it works, but I went with the first answer because for your approach I had to create a new model.